# How to randomly duplicate some documents while importing the data set?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am working on a project, where I have to detect duplicates present in the dataset. Just to create the model, I have taken dataset 20newsgroup from sklearn.

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups

categories = [
    'alt.atheism',
    'talk.religion.misc',
    'comp.graphics',
    'sci.space',
]
print("Loading 20 newsgroups dataset for categories:")
data_train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train', categories=categories,
                                shuffle=True, random_state=42)

data_test = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='test', categories=categories,
                               shuffle=True, random_state=42)
print('data loaded')
```

but this dataset has unique entries, so I have to create duplicates by myself. Here data_train is an array of documents randomly selected for training the model.

Does anyone know what changes to be made to duplicate these documents randomly so in the end I get a dataset with duplicate entries?

Comment: [This question is being discussed on meta.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369945/a-question-is-a-question-why-mine-is-downvoted-instead-of-answered)

Comment: Please provide more details. What does `fetch_20newsgroups` return? How are `data_train` and `data_test` structured?

Comment: thanks for pointing out the fault @BDL , i hope now my question is completely described even if not , tell me

Comment: Now after reading it for the 4th time, I noted that sklearn is not a namespace from you but from a library you are using. I imagine that a lot of programmers looked at it the same way I did and assumed that we are talking about a dataset written by you. I now tagged your question with the appropriate library tag ([tag:scikit-learn]), so you get the correct experts looking at your question. For the future: If you ask a question that is very specific to a library, you should really tag it with the libraries tag and you should mention that you are using the library in your question.

Comment: How are you using `data_train` and `data_test` ? Maybe with more insight into that we can tell you how to duplicate some of that data according to your use case.

Comment: @Jundiaius  `data_train` and `data_test` are then passed into `Simhash` function to produce hash value for each document. hash value of `data_test ` is compared with `data_test`, if any one of these have same value then they are termed as duplicates and the category of trained document is alloted to the testing document.

Answer (score 2):

Return type of `fetch_20newsgroups` is a `Bunch` object. It contains documents in its `data` variable and corresponding label s in `target` variable. So, `data_train.data` is a list and `data_train.target` is a numpy array. You probably using `data_train.data` and `data_train.target` after importing dataset. The code below is to duplicate a row from these containers.

```
import random
def duplicate(X, y):
    index = random.randint(0, len(X) - 1)
    X.append(X[index])
    y = np.append(y, y[index])
    return X, y

X = data_train.data
y = data_train.target

print(len(X))
print(len(y))

X, y = duplicate(X, y)

print(len(X))
print(len(y))
```

---

```
>>> 2034
>>> 2034
>>> 2035
>>> 2035
```

You can do the same thing to `data_test` as well. `duplicate` function duplicates a single row and returns documents, labels. You may want to extend that function to duplicate multiple rows with a single call.

Note: If you want your `Bunch` object to have duplicated rows. You could probably do something like `data_train.data = X` after duplicating rows of `X` but I'm not familiar with this object type so I'm not sure how this object behaves.

**Edit**

For multiple duplicate rows, function above can be called multiple times. A bit more efficient implementation for multiple duplicates is as follows:

```
import random
def duplicate(X, y, no_of_duplicate):
    index_lst = random.sample(range(len(X)), no_of_duplicate)
    y_duplicate = np.empty(no_of_duplicate)
    for i, duplicate_index in enumerate(index_lst):
      X.append(X[duplicate_index])
      y_duplicate[i] = y[duplicate_index]
    y = np.append(y, y_duplicate)
    return X, y

print(len(X))
print(len(y))

X, y = duplicate(X, y, 500)

print(len(X))
print(len(y))
```

Comment: here you've duplicated a single document, so for creating around 500 duplicates or more, i have to run duplicate command that many times? and aslo for 4-5 times duplicate of a single document

Comment: it really worked!. does this duplicate function creates duplicate of document only once or multiple times. like data_train.data[2] has 4 duplicates

Comment: is there any way i can create duplicates before dividing the dataset into training and testing ?

Comment: @shipikasingh, It duplicates a document at most once. It picks these documents without replacement. You may convert `random.sample` line to `random.choices(range(len(X), k=no_of_duplicate)` (Python 3.6 or newer) pick items with replacement. For other question, you import dataset seperately so datasets are already divided when you get them. One solution would be set `subset=all` to import both train and test sets, duplicate rows and then separate them yourself.